# My Python selenium code cannot select a select option

Tags: python, selenium

I cannot select a select option using below Python code..
I have tried to refer many Q&A such as select, execute_script... but they are still not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gR1Y.png)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

seoul_url = 'http://kras.seoul.go.kr/land_info/info/landprice/landprice.do'
browser.get(seoul_url)

time.sleep(1)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sggnm"]/option[11]').click()
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs5Se.png]

Comment: Have you tried /text() at the end ? Or /text()[1]

Comment: Please edit your question to include screenshot in body of question with Ctrl+V instead of a link.

Comment: @David Wooley
Yes, I tried it, but the selenium cannot find the element..

Comment: @Alex B
I added the picture on the body of question.

Answer (score 0):

NEW

Or you can use `ActionChains`. In the code `pos` is the position of the option you want to select

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

actions = ActionChains(driver)

def select_option(id_, pos):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, id_).click()
    actions.send_keys(Keys.DOWN * pos).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

select_option('#sggnm', 10)
time.sleep(1)
select_option('#umdnm', 3)
```

---

OLD

With this code you can change the currently selected option to the desired one without doing a click.

```
# webelement containing the currently selected option
option1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sggnm"]/option[1]')
# string with the text of the 11th option
option11 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sggnm"]/option[11]').text
# replace the current option with the 11th option
driver.execute_script("var el = arguments[0]; arguments[1].innerText = el", option11, option1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your great idea.
But when I replace 11th option to 1st option, second drop-down select option doesn't work..

Comment: @Mooji try the new code i added, to me it works

Comment: @ sound wave
I appreciate your comments.
I modified your codes a little bit to select both options as shown below answer..

Comment: @Mooji Well in the question you did not talk about selecting two options, but only about selecting `#sggnm`, that's why in my code I did not put `#umdnm`. Check the new code which select both options

Answer (score 0):

You have first click on dropdown and then click on the value that you wanted to select like below

**Import**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

**select the desire value**

```
WebElement element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(),'동대문구')]"); // you can choose the value you want
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you cannot click the element as it is not visible.

To make it visible you must click the dropdown menu first as suggested by @Akzy

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url: str = "http://kras.seoul.go.kr/land_info/info/landprice/landprice.do"

driver.get(url)

dropdown_element = driver.find_element_by_id("sggnm")

# Open the dropdown menu first
dropdown_element.click()

option_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sggnm"]/option[11]')

# Now the options are visible we want to click the option in the list
option_element.click()
```

This is untested (for this page) but should work for a generic webpage.

There are other ways of doing this such as sending the down key n times to the dropdown element get the nth option element.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice, but this code still doesn't work.. I can click drop-down menu but the code stops there.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url: str = "http://kras.gb.go.kr/land_info/info/landprice/landprice.do"

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)


def option_click(city):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, city).click()
    time.sleep(1)

def option_select(pos):
    i = 0
    for i in range(pos):
        pyautogui.press("down")
        i += 1

    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(1)


option_click('#sggnm')
option_select(10)

option_click('#umdnm')
option_select(3)
```